# Why wont my filesize() method work?

Tags: php, fopen, filesize, fread

Why wont my `filesize()` method work?  My path works for the `fread()` and `file()` methods, but it wont acknowledge the path on `filesize()`.  Why not?  What should my correct path be?

```
<?php     
    $strLessonDescription = fopen("http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386a28/lovej2ee/exercise5/content/lesson5.txt", "r") 
                            or die ("Error - lesson5.txt cannot be opened");
    $lessonDescription = fread($strLessonDescription, 
                               filesize("http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386a28/lovej2ee/exercise5/content/vocabulary5.txt"));
    fclose($strLessonDescription);

    echo $lessonDescription;        
    $arrLessonVocabulary = array();
    $arrLessonVocabulary = file("http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386a28/lovej2ee/exercise5/content/vocabulary5.txt");

    if (arrLessonVocabulary == NULL)
        print "Error - vocabulary5.txt cannot be opened";
?>
```

Comment: Note that you open a handle to `lesson5.txt` in line 1 but then pass the filesize of `vocabulary5.txt` in line2. Bug or Feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the file you're trying to read is via a remote request, rather than local file, it significantly changes how you want to read that data. Per the [fread() manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php#example-1919), you need to read the file in chunks. Alternatively, try using [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) which should simplify your code:

```
$lessonDescription = file_get_contents('http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386a28/lovej2ee/exercise5/content/vocabulary5.txt');
echo $lessonDescription;
```

Comment: Glad to help. Remember to vote up and mark answers as accepted once you've found what you're looking for.